# Text showing in one line with scroll

Tags: ckeditor

When I insert text into ckeditor its showing good and added into database but in edit form it showing all text into one line with scroll.

**Note :** I notice that this issue is only with Firefox browser

in add form it showing like this

[image]

in edit form it showing like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working now, I don’t know what was the issue may be some css applied on the editor. so I just download the new ckeditor and applied in my app and its working absolutely fine :)